# data from api will show in console.log, but will not render in react app

Tags: reactjs, axios, next.js

I am making a call to my API in a react component. I am using the useState hook. I can make my API call and set my state. When I console.log my state after setting it, it is coming back undefined. My code is below:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { API } from '../../config';
import Layout from '../../components/Layout';

const PendingUser = () => {
  const [pendingUser, setPendingUser] = useState({
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    email: '',
    leAgency: ''
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    getPendingUsers();
  }, []);

  const getPendingUsers = async () => {
    const { data } = await axios.get(`${API}/admin/pendinguser`);
    const pendingUsers = data;
    setPendingUser({
      firstName: pendingUsers.firstName,
      lastName: pendingUsers.lastName,
      email: pendingUsers.email,
      leAgency: pendingUsers.leAgency
    });
    console.log(pendingUser);
  };

  return (
    <table style={{ width: '100%' }}>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>First Name</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>{pendingUser.firstName}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};

export default PendingUser;
```

Comment: State setter functions are in most cases asynchronous, so don't expect the state variable to change on the next line. So if your question is why you don't see the changes right away, that's the answer.

Comment: Do you only have one pending user in your response data? Usually response data from an Axios call like that results in an array of objects that you can then map over and render inside a component.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

Answer (score 0):

The `setPendingUser` call is done asynchronously. This is why right after you make the call you don't immediately get the value inside `pendingUser`.

If you want to know what's in the state each render, I suggest putting the `console.log` just before the `return`:

```
  console.log(pendingUser);
  return (
    <table style={{ width: '100%' }}>
```